# Etymology of initial "g-" in Sicilian "giurana" (frog)

Tags: etymology, arabic, romance-languages, italian, sound-symbolism

Most Romance words for "frog" derive from Latin *rana* (e.g. es. *rana*, it. *rana*, pt. *rã*. See also va. *renoc* ("toad")).

However, an unexpected initial *g-* appears in the cognates of several Gallo-:

- fr. *grenouille*
- oc. *granolha, granhòta*
- ca. *granota, granyota*

and [Italo-Romance](https://archive.org/details/transactionsphi23britgoog/page/n346/mode/2up/search/granocchia) languages:

- it. *granocchia*
- nap. *granògna*
- scn. *giurana*

The [*Trésor de la langue française*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grenouille) suggests that this may be due to onomatopoeic influence (cf. it. *gracidio*), or a related Gaulish word:

> avec un *g-* initial dû soit à l'infl. de mots qui imitent le cri de certains oiseaux (cf. lat. *graculus* ou *gracillare*), soit au croisement avec le gaul. *craxaulus* (*Romania* t. 44, p. 273; cf. aussi [FEW](http://www.atilf.fr/FEW/) t. 2, p. 1295b); cette explication séduisante ne peut convenir pour les formes ital. corresp. (cf. FEW t. 10, p. [60b](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/131321));

Similar explanations are offered for the [Catalan](http://dcvb.iecat.net/results.asp?Word=granota) and Occitan cognates:<sup>1</sup>

> La *g-* de *granota*, com la de *grenouille*, ha estat explicada com a producte d'analogia amb el crit d'aqueix animal (*croasser, croailler*, etc.) segons l'opinió de Schuchardt; en canvi altres lingüistes, com Jud (Rom. xiv, 273), veuen en la dita *g* un efecte de creuament de **rana** amb algun sinònim gàl·lic com **crassantus**.

However the initial *g-* of the Sicilian variant *giurana/girana* is soft, not hard like the other Italian/French/Catalan cognates.

**What is the etymology of *giurana*?**

Several hypotheses spring to mind:

1. also  onomatopoeic
2. from the influence of it. *girino* ("tadpole")
3. a loan from the Arabic جران (jrān) (itself from lat. *rana*).
4. related to Asturian *xaronca*

---

<sup>1. None make note of the similarity with "toad" *crapaud, grapaut, gripau* (fr., oc., ca. resp.).</sup>

<sup>2. [DAS: Perceptions, use & conservation of amphibians by indigenous people](http://theherpetofaunalbiologygroup.weebly.com/uploads/1/4/1/5/14155652/387-_das_man_meets_frogresize_part2.pdf) - Appendix 1: Vernacular names for frogs (and where available, toads and tree frogs) from around the world. (p.49-50)</sup>

Comment: For that matter see, "Indo-Iranian: \*gáru
Iranian: \*gráw, \*gáru (“stick, hollow reed”)[4] ... 
Manichaean Middle Persian: ‎ (grww, “cane, reed”)" \[[\*gweru-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/g%CA%B7%C3%A9ru)] and Ger. *Kröte*, further *Heuschrecke* "grasshopper"